# Using Contains within Where for a list

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-core, dynamic-linq

So I am trying to retrieve results from a collection based on a property. I wanna get any results that hold that value within the list.

This is my code

I have tried with dynamic linq. It's not working

This is dynamic linq. Not working

```
var list = new List<string>(2) { "11111", "22222" };


accounts = accounts.Where("@0.Contains(outerIt.PartnerCompanyId)", list);
```

This is not working as well

```
accounts = accounts .Where(a =>
               a.PartnerCompanyId.Contains(list.Any().ToString()));
```

Also I want the SQL to generate something like this

```
WHERE PartnerCompanyId IN (@gp1, @gp2, @gp3, …)
```

I have been getting this even there are more than 1 value in the list. I want the same number of elements in the list in the parameters.

```
…WHERE PartnerCompanyId IN (@gp1)
```

Is thre any way to accomplish this?

Comment: `accounts = accounts.Where(account => list.Contains(account.PartnerCompanyId));`

Comment: The issue with this is that the im getting this …WHERE PartnerCompanyId IN (gp1). What I am expecting to generate would be more like this
…WHERE PartnerCompanyId IN (gp1, gp2, …)

Comment: FYI `Where(a =>  a.PartnerCompanyId.Contains(list.Any().ToString()))` is going to search for any `PartnerCompanyId` that contains the substring "true" because `list.Any().ToString()` will evaluate to "true" since `list` is not empty.

Comment: Searching around I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258850/linq-query-with-array-input-and-variable-where-statements-advice does the expression tree answer help at all?

Comment: What version of EF Core?

Comment: EF 4.5 with MYSQL Connector

Comment: So, not EF Core? I don't see EF 4.5 listed at Microsoft?

Comment: @GilbertoLangarica try the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question correctly, you have a list of accounts and you want to check whether the accounts contain 'list[0] OR list[1] OR list[2] ...'.

I have managed to get a similar implementation working using Dynamic Linq.

Using your code as a base, here is what I did to get the query to work:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(2) { "11111", "22222" };

string argumentString = "";

for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
{
    argumentString = argumentString + "@" + i;
    argumentString = argumentString + ".Contains(outerIt.PartnerCompanyId)";

    if (i != (list.Length - 1))
    {
        argumentString = argumentString + " or ";
    }
}

var accounts = accounts.Where(argumentString, list.ToArray());
```

The loop will create the string: "@0.Contains(outerIt.PartnerCompanyId) or @1.Contains(outerIt.PartnerCompanyId)"

Once this string is created all you need is a simple Linq query to check all of the items in the list.

Note: you can refer to arguments in order via and array but not a list. As shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/40885380/10253157.

I hope this helps, I had a similar project and it took me quite a while to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This the right way:

```
var myaccounts = accounts.Where(a =>list.Contains(a.PartnerCompanyId));
```

You can see it a text case to run to show it works [here](https://repl.it/repls/ShadyCooperativeInstitute).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [Dynamic Linq](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core), but make sure that the type from the values you search for and the type are the same.

So this will only work if the PartnerCompanyId is also a string.

`var list = new List<string>(2) { "11111", "22222" };`
`accounts.Where("@0.Contains(outerIt.PartnerCompanyId)", list);`

Testing this in LinqPad shows the SQL you would expect:

`-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 7065
DECLARE @p1 Int = 7066
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[Id], *** FROM [MyTable] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Id] IN (@p0, @p1)`